# How can I integrate $\int_{x}^{\infty}\lambda ye^{-\lambda(y-x)}\mathrm{d}y$ by parts

Tags: calculus, conditional-expectation

Conditional expectation can be calculated using integration:

$$\int_{x}^{\infty}yf_{Y|X}(y|x)\mathrm{d}y = \int_{x}^{\infty}\lambda ye^{-\lambda(y-x)}\mathrm{d}y = x + \frac{1}{\lambda}\quad\text{for}\quad x\geq 0$$

My question is how to show $x + \frac{1}{\lambda}\quad\text{for}\quad x\geq 0$

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Could you please tell us what is your progress on the proposed problem?

Comment: I'm trying to show by hand how to integrate $\int_{x}^{\infty}\lambda ye^{-\lambda(y-x)}\mathrm{d}y$ I have a lot written, but I'm incredibly slow with Latex.

Comment: make a change of variable z=y-x, it will separate in two integrals, one is easily (standard example) solved using integration by parts and the other is just integration of an exponential.

Comment: So far I have $\lambda e^{\lambda(x)} \int_{x}^{\infty} ye^{-\lambda(y)}\mathrm{d}y$ ...Kind of stuck here, spinning my wheels

Comment: To calculate the integral $\int_{x}^{\infty}ye^{-\lambda y}\, dy$ by parts, try to integrate the $e^{-\lambda y}$ part and differentiate the $y$ part.

Comment: Integration by parts is $\int udv=uv-\int vdu$ right?, in your case make $u=y$ and $v=-\frac{1}{\lambda}e^{-\lambda y}$

Answer (score 1):

Notice that you are integrating over $y$. So you can factor the terms which do no not depend on it.

Precisely, we have that
\begin{align*}
\int_{x}^{\infty}\lambda y\exp(-\lambda(y-x))\mathrm{d}y & = \exp(\lambda x)\int_{x}^{\infty}\lambda y\exp(-\lambda y)\mathrm{d}y\\\\
\end{align*}

The last one can be computed through integration by parts. Indeed, it results that
\begin{align*}
\int_{x}^{\infty}\lambda y\exp(-\lambda y)\mathrm{d}y & = -y\exp(-\lambda y)\Biggr|_{x}^{\infty} + \int_{x}^{\infty}\exp(-\lambda y)\mathrm{d}y\\\\
& = -y\exp(-\lambda y)\Biggr|_{x}^{\infty} - \frac{\exp(-\lambda y)}{\lambda}\Biggr|_{x}^{\infty}\\\\
& = x\exp(-\lambda x) + \frac{\exp(-\lambda x)}{\lambda}
\end{align*}

Consequently, the proposed integral reduces to
\begin{align*}
\int_{x}^{\infty}\lambda y\exp(-\lambda(y-x))\mathrm{d}y & = \exp(\lambda x)\left(x\exp(-\lambda x) + \frac{\exp(-\lambda x)}{\lambda}\right) = x + \frac{1}{\lambda}
\end{align*}

just as desired.